# Why is `sed expr1 | sed expr2` different to `sed -e expr1 -e expr2`

Tags: sed, group

I was splitting the output from `id` to provide a more readable line-by-list list of groups of which a user is a member:

```
id roaima | sed 's/,/\n\t/g'
uid=1001(roaima) gid=1001(roaima) groups=1001(roaima)
    24(cdrom)
    25(floppy)
    ...
    822413650 (international (uk) location)
```

I wanted to separate the group number from its bracketed name so I extended the expression like this

```
id roaima | sed -e 's/,/\n\t/g' -e '2,$s/(/ (/'
```

However, this did not act as I initially expected. The second expression appeared to have no effect.

Instead, to get the result I wanted, I needed to run two separate `sed` commands, like this:

```
id roaima | sed -e 's/,/\n\t/g' | sed '2,$s/(/ (/'
uid=1001(roaima) gid=1001(roaima) groups=1001(roaima)
    24 (cdrom)
    25 (floppy)
    ...
    822413650 (international (uk) location)
```

Why do I need two `sed` commands in a pipe rather than one with multiple instructions? Or if I can do this with one `sed`, how would I do so?

What I would particularly like is to have the single space between the UID/GID value and its bracketed name for every single item (including the UID and GIDs on the first line), but the caveat is that in my real data I can have groups containing brackets in their names and I don't want the names themselves mangled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sed`, like `awk` or `cut` or `perl -ne` works on each line individually one after the other.

```
sed -e code1 -e code2
```

is actually run as:

```
while(patternspace = getline()) {
  linenumber++
  code1
  code2
} continue {print patternspace}
```

If your code2 is `2,$ s/foo/bar/`, that's:

```
if (linenumber >= 2) sub(/foo/, "bar", patternspace)
```

As your input has only one line, the `sub()` will never be run.

Inserting newline characters in the pattern space in `code1` doesn't make the `linenumber` increase.

Instead, you have one pattern space with several lines in it while processing the *first* and only line of input. If you want to do modifications on the second line and over of that multi-line pattern space, you need to do something like:

```
s/\(\n[^(]*\)(/\1 (/g
```

Though here of course, you might as well do the two operations in one go:

```
id | sed 's/,\([^(]*\)(/\n\t\1 (/g'
```

Comment: awk, and perl -n/p, works on each record which _defaults_ to a line but can be changed; in this case `-vRS=,` or `-054` could help.

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU sed, you could use

```
id username | sed 's/(/ (/4g; s/,/\n\t/g'
```

which adds a space before the 4th and subsequent open parentheses, then replaces the commas.

Comment: That looks interesting. Unfortunately it also affects groupnames that contain brackets such as my example, `international (uk) location`, by inserting an unwanted space in the name itself.

Comment: Then use `s/\([[:digit:]]\+\)(/\1 (/4g` which will only add a space if there are digits before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

What @stéphane-chazelas said is true, but you can always add the space first and split into lines after like this:

```
sed -e 's:\([,=][0-9]*\):\1 :g' -e 's:,:\n\t:g'
```

Or in a single sed script (without `-e`):

```
sed 's:\([,=][0-9]*\):\1 :g; s:,:\n\t:g'
```

We normally use "`/`" as separator of command search (s), but it accepts any character as well, so sometimes it's easier to read using other char like "`:`" to avoid combinations like "`/\`".